# What is st_ino in Unix?

Tags: unix

Can't find proper documentation for it.

It's used inside E-tag header.

For what purpose?

Can someone describe in two words what it is?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the inode number.  It's also a member of `struct stat`, in [stat.h](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html).

Comment: @Beck: Unique per filesystem.  The (st_dev, st_ino) pair should be different for every file on the system.